# Synced array and linked list at fast speed

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I have a group of boxes (struct) that i need to sort constantly in different specific ways so I use a linked list that contains pointers that adress every box to sort them easily, and my program works in two "stages": an edit mode in which I add new boxes, delete them and sort them; and a performance mode, in which I don't need to change the order of the boxes neither add new ones nor delete them, just access to them on the last order that they were set in edit mode, at audio speed with a random index order, that means I access a box in every vector of 16 samples with a sampling rate of 48000 samples for second, this means I access a box every 0.3 milliseconds. Is efficient to use a linked list at this speed? What if I access a box every sample, every 0.02 milliseconds? Is it a good idea to resize memory dynamically for a handle array to store pointers that points to each box and update this array every time after I make a change on the linked list by iterating it so i can access the boxes faster on the perform stage?

Here is my box:

```
typedef struct 
{
    //box stuff...
} box;
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Sequential access is the natural way to traverse a linked list, so yes, it sounds like this data structure is appropriate for your purpose.

Comment: You can also insert-in-order to prevent having to re-sort. (whether you insert in order or bulk-insert and then sort will depend on the frequency at which you need to add to the list) If you have a set of 50,000 boxes that you initially add to the list - add then sort. If you only add a new box once every 1/2 second or so -- add in order.

Comment: Note that you can places the same boxes in multiple data structures. This would allow you to have the data sorted in different ways simultaneously. This may be advantageous if you have a few fixed sorting orders.

Comment: Without more detail, it's impossible to give you a definitive answer.  The size of your data structures is a critically important factor and you've given us nothing to go on.